# Disable button when 1 or more TextBox fields are empty

Tags: c#, mvvm, uwp

I tried a few solution but they seems to be for WPF.

This is what I have for the moment but it doesn't seems to work :

```
<Grid>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text="Username :"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="userNameTextBox" Text="{Binding Username, Mode=TwoWay}" />
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text="Password :" />
            <TextBox x:Name="passwordTextBox" Text="{Binding Password, Mode=TwoWay}" />
        </StackPanel>
        <Button IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=userNameTextBox, Path=Text.Length}" Command="{Binding LoginCommand }" Content="Login" />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

So I want to make the button enables if userNameTextBox and passwordTextBox are not empty.

It stays enabled all the time. What am I doing wrong? Is it possible to do this only via XAML?

```
private string _username;
public string Username
{
    get { return _username; }
    set
    {
        _username = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Username));
        RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(IsButtonEnable));
    }
}

private string _password;
public string Password
{
    get { return _password; }
    set {
        _password = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Password));
        RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(IsButtonEnable));
    }
}

private bool _isButtonEnable;
public bool IsButtonEnable
{            
    get
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_username) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_username)
            && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(_password) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_password))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can set a boolean value to disable that button. Here is sample code given below=>

**XAML:**

```
<Grid>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text="Username :"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="userNameTextBox" Text="{Binding Username, Mode=TwoWay}" />
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text="Password :" />
            <TextBox x:Name="passwordTextBox" Text="{Binding Password, Mode=TwoWay}" />
        </StackPanel>
        <Button IsEnabled="{Binding IsButtonEnable}" Command="{Binding LoginCommand }" Content="Login" />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

In **ViewModel** Add IsButtonEnable Property Like

```
#region Property IsButtonEnable: bool
public bool IsButtonEnable
{
    get
    {
        if( !string.IsNullOrEmpty(_Username) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_Username)
            && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(_Password) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_Password))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}

#endregion

#region Property Username: string
private string _Username;
public string Username
{
    get { return _Username; }
    set
    {
        _Username = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(Username));
        NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(IsButtonEnable));
    }
}

#endregion

#region Property Password: string
private string _Password;
public string Password
{
    get { return _Password; }
    set
    {
        _Password = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(Password));
        NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(IsButtonEnable));
    }
}

#endregion
```

**Note:** Here `NotifyPropertyChanged` will call `IsButtonEnable` to update UI when either `Username` or `Password` is changed. You want to add more property then add them and update if condition inside `IsButtonEnable` `get` section.
 Please check and let me know.

Comment: Looks great and want to try it but stupid question, I never used 'NotifyPropertyChanged'. Which library should I use?

Comment: There are many frameworks are available I am using MVVM.Framework library. You can also check that link [LINK](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/explain-inotifypropertychanged-in-wpf-mvvm/)

Comment: Yes i'm using MVVM, MvvmLightLibsStud10 but it doesn't reconize NotifyPropertyChanged, Shouldn't it be RaisePropertyChanged?

Comment: Is there anything called `RaisePropertyChanged`

Comment: Correct 'RaisePropertyChanged' exists however it doesn't disables the button :/

Comment: It works for me both in silverlight and WPF. Replace NotifyPropertyChanged to RaisePropertyChanged in my code and then you can try.

Comment: That's what I did. But it doesn't work, remember I'm using UWP. Updated my question with you suggestion.

Comment: When I debug it never comes in IsButtonEnable property

Comment: Can you update your question with you full minimal xaml  and ViewModel *.cs Code ? Then I can check where things goes wrong.

Comment: Sorry mate, my fault, I used the wrong binding name in my xaml 'IsEnabled' instead of 'IsEnable'. Now it works.

Comment: Maybe a detail question, now the button enables when you click outside the TextBox Control. How to enable make it immediatly without having to click outside the TextBox?

Comment: Please Check `<TextBox x:Name="passwordTextBox" Text="{Binding Password, Mode=TwoWay}" UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged />` UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged or other like `Explicit` and `Default`